# Sharing the graph to another user in Galaxybase

Tags: graph-databases

When I share the graph to another user in Galaxybase, can that user modify the data of the graph? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be determined by the permissions set at the time of sharing. Currently, three roles - publisher, editor and read-only - can be set at the time of sharing.

The publisher permission can modify the schema, incremental derivative operation, and modify data operation; the editor permission can do the CRUD operations; the read-only permission only allows query operation for the graph.